# Is it possible to make master page get called first instead of the called page - asp.net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, call, code-behind

Is it possible to make master page get called first instead of the called page - asp.net 4.0. I mean for example i have home page and i have master page. When i called the home page it goes to the home page code behind first then it goes to the master page code behind. Is it possible to call master page code behind first ?

ASP.net 4.0 , C# thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

The hierarchy is that the master page is actually nested *within* each content page.

The sequence of events is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3.aspx).

Comment: hello thanks for the answer. can i write a function which will be called before all of the content pages init ? But at this function i need to be able to retrieve the visitor IP address and need to be able to access the session of the visitor. Thank you.

Comment: When do you need this function to fire? Every page load or when session starts?

Comment: Actually only when the session starts. I will init some sessions variables according to the visitor. Such as the assigning visitor country value according to the visitor IP address.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG - Then you should just do that in the `global.asax` in `session_start`.

Comment: also this global.asax sessions start is thread safe right ? it will be unique for every visitor ?

Comment: thank you for your valuable time. i just learned a very useful thing :D

Answer (score 1):

If you have to write common function in each content page.You can avoid t by creating a base class and derive each content pages from that base class instead of the default base class `System.Web.UI.Page`

Other method as above mentioned write function in global.asax